# Encode Cloud Media Files to be DASH streamable via C#

Tags: c#, uwp, google-drive-api, streaming, mpeg-dash

I have written an app in C# that downloads chunk content via HttpRequest, I was wondering is it possible to stream the content from any of these cloud (Google Drive, Dropbox, OneDrive) services as a HLS, DASH or RTMP stream?
If so does anyone know how the URL is built for it? I cannot find much of anything on this on the internet.
How can I make a dash encoding profile based on a media file and upload it to google drive to play the actual media via DASH stream.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering is it possible to stream the content from any of these cloud (Google Drive, Dropbox, OneDrive) services as a HLS, DASH or RTMP stream

I think it is possible since there is a service named [Bitmovin](https://bitmovin.com/) which supports cloud video encoding. It can encode your video to both `MPEG-DASH` and `HLS`. Your input videos can be transfered to the Bitmovin cloud encoding service through various input protocols such as HTTP or FTP servers, Google Cloud Storage, Amazon S3, Microsoft Azure, Aspera. Details for how to do please reference [Setup Adaptive Bitrate Streaming with DASH and HLS](https://bitmovin.com/tutorials/setup-adaptive-bitrate-streaming-dash-hls/).

For uwp app, there is an [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/AdaptiveStreaming)  showed create media source from adaptive stream Uri. The Uri in this sample is from [Azure media service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-overview) that it may also help encode video file. Detail implements you can have a try.

Comment: Since you are using C# I'd recommend using the Bitmovin-C# API-Client to communicate with the service. https://bitmovin.com/c-video-streaming-encoding-api-net/ There are a lot of examples in their GitHub Repository on how to get started.

Comment: @Sunteen Wu  - MSFT Thanks for the comments Bitmovin is really expensive, I realise it is powerful and ideal but really if my product doesn't outweigh the costs it is not worth it.

Comment: @Tigraine Thanks for the comments Bitmovin is really expensive, I realise it is powerful and ideal but really if my product doesn't outweigh the costs it is not worth it.

Comment: @SeanRyan did you want to do this without a tool help?

Comment: @Sunteen Wu - MSFT I just want to do it all via an API in C# or C++.

Comment: @Sunteen Wu - MSFT I cannot justify paying for something when I have no user revenue.  If MSFTs FFMPEGINTEROP CreateMSsFromURI worked then maybe I would not need this :)